# Specifying different hosts for read and write with grails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Is there a configuration option for Grails/GORM to allow for different hosts for read and write operations? I'd like to be able to have all of my SELECT queries hit a read replica host while INSERTS, UPDATES AND DELETES would hit the master database. I have been unable to find any documentation pointing to a simple solution to this issue.

Comment: use a separate db object for each. The read replica is delayed and occasionally you'll need to do a query on a item just inserted in which case a master read will get you a correct results and a slave read wont.

Comment: take a look at CQRS - micronaut being microservices can be made into small apps which each doing their own thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a configuration option for Grails/GORM to allow for different
>   hosts for read and write operations?

No.  You can configure GORM to communicate with as many different databases as you like and you can write code that only reads from certain databases and only writes to others but there is no way to tell GORM that all writes go to one place or set of places and reads go to another place or set of places.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Not the answer I was hoping for but very helpful none the less. Can you point me towards documentation that might show how this would work with domain objects?

Comment: "Can you point me towards documentation that might show how this would work with domain objects?" - I am not sure what you mean by "work with domain objects". That is really all that GORM does is work with domain objects.  If you are looking for multiple datasource docs in particular, http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#multipleDataSources is a good resource.  I hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!